# NetworkX in python

Tags: python, networkx

I want to define a weighted graph where node ids are the name of persons and links between the nodes are directed. Each edge has a label representing relationship and a trust value which is a real number.

Then, I need to find a path between a pair of users to calculate indirect trust between the two. I have written following code, but I am getting following error:

> File "osn_graph.py", line 30, in 
>       trust=trust*float(G[list[i]][list[i+1]][trust])
>       KeyError: 1

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
import networkx as nx  
G = nx.DiGraph()  
f = open("osndata.txt","rb")  
while 1:  
    line = f.readline()  
    if not line: 
        break  
    src = line.rstrip('\n')  
    G.add_node(src)  
    line = f.readline()  
    dest = line.rstrip('\n')  
    G.add_node(dest)  
    line = f.readline()  
    t = int(line)*0.01  
    line = f.readline()  
    r = line.rstrip('\n')  
    G.add_edge(src, dest, weight=t, relation=r)  
f.close()  
try:  
    list = nx.dijkstra_path(G, "akash", "jitendra")  
    trust = 1  
    i = 0  
    for j in range(0, len(list) - 1):  
       trust = trust * float(G[list[j]][list[j + 1]]['weight'])  
        i += 1  
    print trust  
except nx.NetworkXNoPath:  
    print "There is no path between nodes"
```

Comment: Any chance you could stretch to a *little bit* more information than *"it is not working"*?

Comment: I am getting following error:                                                                   File "osn_graph.py", line 30, in <module>                                                                                                       
    trust=trust*float(G[list[i]][list[i+1]][trust])                                                 
KeyError: 1

Comment: So what's `G`? `i`? `list` (**terrible** name, by the way)? `trust`? Have you done *any* debugging?

Comment: Quick comment - you've got too much space between `try` and `except`.  You really should only have the line that you expect might give the error.  Look at `try..except..else`

Comment: What is the role of `i` in the `for` loop at the end?

Comment: If you can provide a sample input so that people can just copy and paste and get the error, it's much easier to search for the error.